# Mechanical Power (Application) and Electrical Power (Stepper Motor) Discrepancy

Tags: power, motor

For my application I need a torque of \$\tau=0.87 \, Nm \$ and a speed of \$ w=140 \, RPM \approx 14.65 \, rad/s \$. This gives me a mechanical power \$ P_m=12.75 \, W\$.
$$
P_m=\tau w
$$
I have selected [this](http://en.nanotec.com/products/566-st8918-stepper-motor-nema-34/) stepper motor, which gives me the desired speed torque characteristics.
[image]
Now, I want to double check that the motor will generate enough electrical power to match or exceed the mechanical power requirements (\$P_m<=P_e\$).
$$P_e=UI$$
From the motor spec \$I=6.37\$, \$R=0.3\$. As recommeded [here](http://www.stepperboard.com/CalculatingMotorCurrent.htm), I obtain \$ U=IR\$; this gives me a value \$U=1.91 \, V\$.

Now this gives me an electrical power of \$P_e \approx 12 \, W\$, which is lower than my \$ P_m\$. Looking at the graph I would expect a \$P_e\$ considerably higher than my \$P_m\$ requirement.  **Question: why is \$P_e\$ not higher?**

Comment: 12w is the electrical power consumed by one coil when operating as a space heater - what you might call the "parasitic resistance loss".

Answer (score 1):

To much text for a comment.

- Your link leads to 6 differnt moters, none of them is listed with 0.3 Ω
- You can not use the DC resistance to make power calculations
- The inductance is not stable, it changes with speed and load
- Stepper motors are supplied with a pulsed DC voltage/current, that makes power calculations a lot more difficult than with DC or AC currents
- Stepper motors have a bad efficiency, if the diagram above has no bugs, it shows a situation with *Pm = 46.2 W* and *Pe = 305 W* (Eventually this is peak and not average power)

I don't think that i'm wrong when i concluded that you will need a lot of profound electrotechnical and mathematical knowledge the make reliable calculations with stepper motors.

Comment: All I need is a reasonable ballpark estimate to:
(i) know that the motor will have the desired mechanical performance (I guess the torque -- speed characteristic graph is sufficient for that?)
(ii) choose the correct power supply.